# PHP get sessions where name is like

Tags: php, session

I am storing sessions and the only thing that differentiates them is the ending id, I store them in this form `chat_625265` the random numbers on the end is an ID. I would like to select PHP sessions where they have the `chat_` beginning and then store the trailing number in a variable e.g. `$session_num`.

I am using the PHP session mechanism, `$_SESSION['some_name']=$some_content`

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you storing them and how?

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in PHP session mechanism?

Comment: I am using the PHP session mechanism, `$_SESSION['some_name']=$some_content`

Comment: So you're trying to load session data belonging to users that are not the current session user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {

    if (strpos($key, 'chat_') !== false) {

        //echo "SESSION['{$key}'] has a value of {$value}\n";

        $session_num[] = str_replace('chat_', '', $key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to operate under the assumption that what you're *trying* to do is load the session of another user.

While it is *technically* possible to do this, it's something you should not do.  Needing to do this is a sign that you have placed the wrong data in the wrong place.

Sessions are intended to work around the fact that HTTP is a stateless protocol.  They're a convenient place to stick temporary data that only the current user making the current request will need to reference.

Data that *other sessions* need to reference should go in the database, not in the session.  You're going to need to change your application so that you're storing the data in the correct place.

Note that this is *not* the same thing as storing sessions in the database.  Treat session data as a binary blob that you are not permitted to read from SQL or outside of the PHP session mechanism.

Further, make sure you are not exposing the session IDs of other users.  Doing so can be a tremendous security risk.